# Filling empy spaces around and image on a responsive sidebar

Tags: html, css, html-table, viewport, sidebar

To make it quick, I have a responsive sidebar ([using viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidebar_responsive.asp)) with an image at the top. The sidebar is 200px wide, and my image is set to width 200px. So as long as my sidebar stays on the left, it looks nice. When the sidebar moves to the top, image is centered (which is correct) but then I get space before and after the image and those spaces are the color of the container (sidebar). I want those spaces to be black.

I tried with width:100%. Since the image needs to be 200px it will fit the container when it's on the left. But as soon as it moves to the top, the container width change to fit the screen/window size and the image gets really too big. Setting a max width of 200px solves the problem, but I still get those spaces on each side.

I thought of using a table with 3 columns. But I am unsure on how to set 1st and 3rd columns to use the remaining space while the center column is always 200px (wrapped around image which is fixed at 200px). So lets say screen is 700px, center will be 200px and 1st and 3rd should be 250px each. I tried using a class and under the @media set it to 250px for the 700px max width @media and 50px for the 400px @media but seems it doesn't work. Can't get the cell to take all the space (because it's empty?) and even setting black on the cell directly or via the class, the sidebar color is always there (maybe there's a display setting I should add to make it over the sidebar?). And when it's full screen like on a PC, so more than 700px, 1st and 3rd row shouldn't affect the look and be at 0px, or 1px each and image could be set at 198px. It doesn't matter if I have a 1px black on each side. It will fit anyways.

I am out of idea and I'm a noob at HTML/CSS.

I didn't put any coding as I am not sure what part of my CSS would be required (most of it is in the link above, I only changed the colors). As for the HTML part there shouldn't be anything of value.

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" border="0" style="width:200px" class="center">
  
  <table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="index.html">Français</a></td>
      <td><a href="index_en.html">English</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <a class="active" href="index_en.html">Main page</a>
  <a href="files.html">Files</a>
  <a href="video_en.html">Videos</a>
</div>
```

Note that the  logo is not in a table. I removed the table part from my coding. Because as soon as I add a table, I do get some padding around the table, showing the sidebar color around the table.

Can anything be done ? Like a really quick fix ? There must be something I am missing. Using viewport and @media to scale/move things around is new to me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: its because the images height is less then the sidebars height. as such image needs either an `contain`, `cover` or `strech` value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, if it can help someone eventually. It is probably not the best practice or the best solution, but it works.

I created a logo with a width of 700x (my logo is 200px, so I added 250px black bar each side) so it can scale down to 400px (for my viewport). Then in my CSS I added :

```
.logo {
    background: url(/img/logo700px.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Then in my HTML I changed my `img` for

```
<div class="logo">&nbsp;</div>
```

It works like a charm. Well.... Tested on Chrome and Firefox both PC and Android. So now my image is always centered on the sidebar. On big screen it only shows the 200px required (limited by the sidebar CSS) and when it switches to topbar with larger width it centers the logo and keeps the black bars to full the `div` container.

Looking at the source code of https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/not-responsive.html (taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) helped me understand and adapt it to my needs.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you added

```
padding="0"
```

to inside the img tag, it should do the trick (ex:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<img src="/img/logo.png" border="0" style="width:200px" class="center" padding="0">
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="index.html">Français</a></td>
        <td><a href="index_en.html">English</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <a class="active" href="index_en.html">Main page</a>
  <a href="files.html">Files</a>
  <a href="video_en.html">Videos</a>
</div>
```

Please remember that I'm still new to HTML, so if this doesn't work, please let me know!

---

Okay so someone corrected me on my padding="0".Reading over the question again, you could try setting

```
width="auto"
```

and then change the max width in your css heading? I'm kinda at a loss, and I'm not sure how to help :(.

Comment: `padding: 0;` is the default value. So it does nothing that isnt done by default. The white space is created as the image does not have an infinte height.

Comment: `width=auto` will not fix it as the image still gets all the width leaving me with an image too big. I don't think anything with the image will fix the blank space left by the fixed size. My guess would be that the best way is to use a table and do something with first and third cell to adapt and cover the sidebar color when the image is not wide enough.

Comment: Maybe if I can specify what image should be there with the @media, so when screen size is max 400px, I show my 400px image with `width=100%` and `max-width:400px` (logo with black bands on each side) and when it's 700px max, logo with larger black bands on each side. That would do the trick.

Would that make sense ? Would it be possible ?

Comment: Good job figuring it out!